# collecting all options in shell

Tags: linux, shell, getopts

I'm trying to forward all the options collected to be used in another command in shell script.

For example if a script is run like:

```
./master -o -t -k Arg1
```

In master

1. The getopts are `.:o.:t.:k.:r` (r is not used in current run)
2. runs another scrip and all the options used for should be used for the internal script

```
./slave -o -t -k Arg2
```

I want all the (`-o -t -k`), or any other options combination entry to be used - how do I do that?

Comment: If you just wanted all the options received to be passed to slave then ./slave $@ will do the trick.

Comment: @user3088572: If you're going to use a variant on the `$@` notation, make sure you use `"$@"` to preserve spaces inside arguments.

Comment: What do you think the dots in the option string do?  There's no mention of them in the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html).  If it isn't a special meaning, then none of `-o`, `-t`, `-k` or `-r` accept an argument, but if you use `-. something` on the command line, the `something` is mandatory (and the fact that you said `.:` multiple times is immaterial; the first was sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `./slave ${*/Arg1/Arg2}`. This will send all the arguments from `master` to `slave`, after replacing `Arg1` with `Arg2`. The nice thing is that `$*` evaluates all your inputs as one string (unlike `$@`), allowing for a simple replacement.

Comment: See comment from Jonathan Leffler aobut preserving spaces. "$@" will preserve spaces. $* won't.